# i want to write a function in python named cont() which sends a message "continue" and which should take no argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i want to write a function in python named cont() which sends a message "continue" and which should take no argument.the function should print the message yes,y or Y.then return true otherwise false. i have done it but there is an error.

```
def cont():
    x = input("enter any word of your choice")
    for letter in 'x':
        if letter == '[0]':
            a = input ("continue")
            if a == 'yes' == 'y' == 'Y' :
                continue
            print 'current letter will be:',letter
        else:
            print x

if __name__=="__main__":
    cont()
```

Comment: def cont():
    x = input("enter any word of your choice")
    for letter in 'x':
        if letter == '[0]':
            a = input ("continue")
            if a == 'yes' == 'y' == 'Y' :
                continue
            print 'current letter will be:',letter
        else:
            print x

if __name__=="__main__":
    cont()

Comment: Your code has numerous errors.  I suggest you look at [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial) and begin with simpler bits of code.

Comment: If you are using python 2, then you should use `raw_input()`, not `input()`.  If you are using python 3 you should use `print(x)`, not `print x`.  Please clarify which version of python you are using.  Your `if` statement testing "yes" is completely malformed.

Comment: This is completely wrong `if a == 'yes' == 'y' == 'Y' `. I assume this is homework in which case you need to refer to your notes from class to get the basics right.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the code that you supplied and the description that you wrote, do not agree with each other. There is no attempt to `return` any value, indeed, there is nothing to suggest what the decision of `True` or `False` would be based upon.
Assuming that you are using python 2.7, this should get you started:

```
def cont():
    x = raw_input("Enter any word of your choice: ")
    for letter in x:
#    if letter == '[0]':
        a = raw_input ("Continue? ")
        if a == 'yes' or a == 'y' or a == 'Y' :
#            continue
            print 'Current letter will be:',letter
        else:
            print x
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont()
```

I have no idea what you were attempting to do with the `if letter == '[0]':` or the `continue` lines, so I have commented them out.
If you wish to return a value, simply `return True` or `return False` at the point of your choosing in the code. The other option is to set a variable to `True` or `False` and then, as the last statement of `cont()` use the `return` keyword with the variable.

Note: if you are using python3 the `raw_input` becomes `input` and the `print` commands become `print()`